# Unable to scrape a specific part using Simple HTML DOM

Tags: php, html, web-scraping, simple-html-dom

I am trying to scrap a e-retail website to get the prices of the products but I get an empty response for the specific portion of the site which contains the product details.

This is the link I'm trying https://www.flipkart.com/american-tourister-jasper-backpack/p/itmea59yztwfzfk8?pid=BKPEA59YWHMDHJZS to scrape

This is my code

```
<?
include 'simple_html_dom.php';
$html = file_get_html('https://www.flipkart.com/american-tourister-jasper-backpack/p/itmea59yztwfzfk8?pid=BKPEA59YWHMDHJZS');
foreach($html->find('div._2Cl4hZ') as $e)
echo $e->plaintext. '<br>';
?>
```

I think some algorithm is blocking the DOM from scraping the contents of the data inside the div _2Cl4hZ. When I scrape the complete page in plaintext all the other data gets scraped and I can view them except for the data inside that div. Is there anyway to do this?

Comment: Try `$html->find("div._2Cl4hZ",0) ` if it fails try with simple method like PHP native dom.

Comment: You won't get the same html with this link as you see displayed on page, because it's loaded later through ajax calls to their API. Either try to talk to API or follow ajax call "breadcrumbs" with browser's dev tools.

Comment: I can see that div in the response but it's empty.